# How do I enable tls / ssl protection back in composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I issued a disable-tls not long ago because I thought it would fix the issue that I have, how can I enable it back?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest option would be to edit `~/.composer/config.json` file and remove line with `disable-tls` setting (default value is `false`).

Or run:

```
composer config -g -- disable-tls false
```